# how to improve my Visualization graph?observation points are too close

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, logistic-regression

```
# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 
                                   0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 
                                    0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
                     alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

as in the below graph , I am unable to decrease size of observation points as they are way to close and my contour line is zic-zack.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vrir.png
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BQUH.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Try playing around with the size parameter in the scatter plot using something like `s=5` or  `s=10`

Comment: the graph becomes better but, I want observation points to be smaller